# Will not open a new tab in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

I wonder if anybody can help me. I'm trying to open a hyperlink into another tab within IE. But everything I've tried doesn't seem to want to work. I'm working in ASP.NET c# because of client requests.

My Code looks like:

```
<a href="inv_dets.aspx?invID=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InvoiceID") %>">
   view
</a>
```

Does anybody know how to alter this code so that it opens up within a new tab inside IE???

Comment: Wow. Never seen a question with closing votes for nearly all categories.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a target="_blank" href="inv_dets.aspx?invID=<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "InvoiceID") %>">
   view
</a>
```

Comment: Note that this will open in either a new tab or in a new window, depending on the user's browser & browser settings. There's no way to guarantee the link opens in a new tab, if the browser's set up to open in a new window then that's what you're going to get.

Comment: Tried it and doesn't work

Comment: Like Chris said correctly, this depends on your browser and it's settings. There is no guarantee it will open in a new tab. Just google for "target blank" and you'll find hundreds of information.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is about opening in a new tab, the answer is that you can add a target of "_blank", but that you can never be guaranteed it will open in a new tab versus a new window, as that is a setting controlled by IE (or whatever browser the user has).  To see the settings in IE 10, go to Tools->Internet Options->Click the "Tabs" button.  You can specify whether IE decides how links are opened, always open then in a new window, or always open in a new tab.  There is no way to control this via your own code.

Comment: I've changed the settings and it still doesn't want to open in a new tab.